# Passing arrays to functions PHP

Tags: php

I just started learning PHP, and I came across the following code, which I'm having trouble to understand:

```
<?php
function f($v, $n) {
    if ($n <= 0) return 1;
    else
    return $v[$n-1] * f($v, $n-2) + 1;
}
$a = array(0,1,2,3);
print (f($a, 4));
?>
```

This script returns the value 7. I can't understand how the `f($v, $n-2)` part is returning the value 2, since `$v` is an array. Shouldn't I have to put something like `$v[number]` so it can have a value? The commands `echo "$a"` (or $v) and `print($a)` return the "array" message, followed by a PHP notice.

What value would `$v` receive in this case?

Thanks very much!

Comment: `f()` is called recursively, so the parameter `$v` is the same array `$a` for every call. Only `$n` is changed for the recursive calls. In which line do you think `$v` is used as a number?

Comment: `f($v, $n-2)` is the same kind of thing as `f($a, 4)`.

Comment: @KarstenKoop  I thought that in line 5 the syntax was incorrect, but I just realized it’s an calculation of the function inside the function itself. So it was not being used as a number. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so your $f() is a lambda function and so can be triggered by just calling the value associated.

In your array, you got 4 positions that go from 0 to 3;

When you execute the lambda targetting the index of 4, below will happen:

*For index 4*
v[(4-1)] = 3

`3 * f($v, (4-2)) + 1`

*f($v, (4-2))*
v[(2-1)] = 1

`1 * f($v, (2-2)) + 1`

*f($v, (2-2))*
If is triggered as $n <= 0. Returns 1 automatically;

So putting them together from bottom to top, you will have:

3 * (1 * 1 + 1) + 1

Following the math rules, first resolve what is under parenthesis, then multiplication, then sum:

3 * 2 + 1 = 6 + 1 = 7

Hope it was clear!

Comment: Thank you! I thought the syntax was incorrect, but I just realized that it’s a calculation inside a calculation. So stupid! Thanks a lot for the very clear explanation.

Comment: @RodrigoVieira may I ask for an upvote if the answer satisfied you? :)

Comment: yeah, I upvoted you! It’s just that my reputation is lower than 15, so it’s not visible just yet. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The function is called recursively. Here is what the formula behind the function call looks like behind the scenes:

```
3 * (1 * (1) + 1) + 1
```

The values inside parentheses are results of recursive calls.

Result is *7*.